# Slow connection speed when pushing repository to CloudCommit

Tags: bash, git, terminal, gitlab, aws-codecommit

I am working in Germany and would like to work on a repository with some guys in the US. The problem is when we push our changes to our self-hosted gitlab server, the connection is fine but, you can guess it, when they trying to download these changes it takes too much time. So we searched for a solution and found AWS CodeCommit. And I am now trying to upload our git there but when I choose US East 1 as the repository server the connection is still too slow (around 350KiB/s).

**Do you have any suggestion how to improve the speed or how to share a big repository (70GB with lots of small files, so Git LFS is not an option) around the globe?**

Answer (score 1):

Git is a DVCS. The "D" stands for "Distributed." My first reaction would be to take advantage of that. Have a gitlab server in Germany, and another in the US. Have them regularly fetch from each other. This will become an asynchronous process such that you're not waiting to get commits and branches, though there will be an information delay if things were just pushed in the other jurisdiction.

So, most of the day in Germany, you're pushing your commits to the local gitlab, and it regularly syncs with the site in the US. When your US coworkers get in, most of your work has already been pushed, and they can quickly download to their workstations. When they're done their work, it eventually gets synced back to Germany such that when you start your next day, it's already basically local.

There's nothing in git that says there can only be one "master server." Maybe, for ease, you only manage your pull requests on one site, but most of the work will sync across when no one is waiting on it, making it feel faster than it really is.

Comment: Yes, we actually thought about that. But that means I can just sync our Gitlab Server with the AWS CodeSummit and it will be fine, right? Thanks for your fast response.

Comment: The AWS CodeSummit server would be one such possible solution, yes. We regularly commit both to internal git servers and github, it only gets messy when both sites are trying to commit to master, which is why picking only one location to merge PRs becomes easier, but otherwise if you're just pushing branches back and forth, should be fine.